# How do I implement Minecraft Forge Config GUI (1.8.x)

Tags: java, gui, minecraft-modding, configuration

So I have recently been working on a minecraft 1.8.9 forge mod, just to play around and see what there is (eventually I am planning on making a utilities mod with versions for 1.8-1.19, which is why I'm so far back).  I have had no problems... until I got to configs.  I already have code to create and read from a config file, but I can not figure out how to use MinecraftForge's mod options > config menu to allow GUI modification of the settings.  I have had no luck finding any information on how to do this back in 1.8, so if anyone could help me out a bit (linking sources, giving example code, or referring me to a forge class that has the relevant code in it), I would greatly appreciate it.

TL;DR
I need help implementing forge's config gui system.

My current config code (in the Main class):

```
public static Configuration config;
    private File confDir;
    
    public static Logger lmao;

    public static Configuration getConfig()
    {
        return config;
    }
    @EventHandler
    public void preinit(FMLPreInitializationEvent event) {
        lmao = event.getModLog();

        confDir = event.getModConfigurationDirectory();
        config = null;
        File configFile = new File(confDir,"config.cfg");
        config = new Configuration(configFile);
        syncConfig(true);
        event.getModLog().log(Level.ALL,"Preinitialization complete.");
    }
    private static void syncConfig(boolean load)
    {
        List<String> propOrder = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (!config.isChild)
        {
            if (load)
            {
                config.load();
            }
            Property enableGlobalCfg = config.get(CATEGORY_GENERAL, "enableGlobalConfig", false).setShowInGui(false);
            if (enableGlobalCfg.getBoolean(false))
            {
                Configuration.enableGlobalConfig();
            }
        }

        Property prop;

        //set prop value, then:
        //propOrder.add(prop.getName());

        prop = config.get(CATEGORY_GENERAL,"testbool",false);
        prop.comment = "for testing purposes";
        prop.setLanguageKey("mod.conf.testbool");
        propOrder.add(prop.getName());

        prop = reConf.get(CATEGORY_GENERAL,"testvar","can you see this?");
        prop.comment = "for testing purposes only";
        prop.setLanguageKey("mod.conf.teststring");
        propOrder.add(prop.getName());

        config.setCategoryPropertyOrder(CATEGORY_GENERAL, propOrder);


        if (config.hasChanged())
        {
            config.save();
        }
    }
          public static void syncConf(boolean load1) {
          //public configuration sync method
        syncConfig(load1);
    }
    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onConfigChangedEvent(OnConfigChangedEvent event)
    {
        if (event.modID.equals(MODID))
        {
            if (Configuration.CATEGORY_GENERAL.equals(event.configID))
            {
                syncConfig(false);
            }
        }
    }
          //much of this was taken from or inspired by forge's source code, and adapted to work with this mod.
```

I have written some GUI code, but managed to mess it up enough that I will just rewrite it based off ForgeGuiFactory.java later, which is why I have attached no GUI code here.

If anyone can help, please do.  If this post is breaking a forum rule, DEFINITELY tell me, since I need to know.

Thanks ahead of time,

-MiSt_Rocky

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need 3 things:

- A class that extends `net.minecraftforge.fml.client.config.GuiConfig`:

```java
public class ExampleConfig extends GuiConfig {
        ExampleConfig(GuiScreen parent) {
            super(
                    parent,
                    new ConfigElement(config.getCategory(Configuration.CATEGORY_CLIENT)).getChildElements(),
                    "modid",
                    false,
                    false,
                    "title"
            );
        }
    }
```

Take a look at the `GuiConfig` class for what the parameters mean. The most important one here is the 2nd one, which is the list of elements this gui will have.

`new ConfigElement(config.getCategory(Configuration.CATEGORY_CLIENT)).getChildElements()` will get all the elements inside the `"client"` category. (You do not need to do this, I just thought it'd be cool to mention)

- A class that implements `net.minecraftforge.fml.client.IModGuiFactory`:

```java
public class GuiFactory implements IModGuiFactory {
    @Override
    public void initialize(Minecraft minecraft) {}

    @Override
    public Class<? extends GuiScreen> mainConfigGuiClass() {
        return ExampleConfig.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<RuntimeOptionCategoryElement> runtimeGuiCategories() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public RuntimeOptionGuiHandler getHandlerFor(RuntimeOptionCategoryElement runtimeOptionCategoryElement) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The only notable thing here is the `mainConfigGuiClass` method, which returns the class made on the step before.

- Add the `GuiFactory` to your `Mod` annotation:

```java
@Mod(
    // ... previous arguments
    guiFactory = "path.to.GuiFactory"
)
public class ExampleMod {
    // ...
}
```

With all of this done, once you launch the game, the `Config` options in the mod options menu should no longer be greyed out.

Hope this helps.